# Ford Fiesta MK6 front fog light

Tags: ford, fiesta

The glass cover of one of the fog lights has broken on my car. I thought changing it couldn't be too hard a  job and so I already have a whole fog light part to replace it myself. The Haynes Manual I have suggests there are to different styles of Fiesta fog light access that require it to be changed 2 different ways, either pop off the plastic panel and change it, or unscrew a screw pop off the panel and change it.

Now, the problem is... My Fiesta isn't either of those!!

From what I have deduced I can only work out I have to take off the entire front bumper to access the fog light. Is this right or am I missing something?

If necessary I could take a picture of where the fog light resides if it would aide anyone in knowing how to replace the fog light on my Fiesta?

Comment: @Mark Johnson It is a UK Ford Fiesta, 05 plate (2005) 1.4 diesel, GHIA. The Hyanes Manual is for years 2002-2008.

Comment: On some vehicles you need to remove the headlamp to get at the fog light.  I'm not familiar with Fiestas, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @Tim I'll try that tomorrow while it's light (and hopefully not raining!).

Comment: @Tim removing the headlight provided access to thru fog light

Comment: Awesome, I turned the comment into an answer if you want to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like on some Fiestas you need to remove the headlamp to access the fog light. http://www.fordownersclub.com/forums/topic/31017-new-fog-lights/

Answer (score 0):

U can access the spot lights in the front bumper from the bottom, u don't need to take anything else off.... go under the front of the car ull see them couple of screws and there done!!